# Are SKIP and LIMIT based on the ORDER clause?

Tags: neo4j

I have a query like so:

```
MATCH
  (card:`card`),
  (event:`event`),
  (card)<-[:includes_card]-(event)
WHERE
  card.id = "0000000978LBtZz08W5439Mvo"
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (actor:`user`),
  (card)-[includes_actor_rel:includes_actor]->(actor)
RETURN event, actor, includes_actor_rel
ORDER BY event.created_at DESC
SKIP 50 
LIMIT 5
```

Do the `SKIP` and `LIMIT` clauses work over the number of event nodes returned? I'm asking because, while I'd like to return the actor and relationship, I don't want the actor and relationship nodes to affect the pagination.

If this is not the case, what is the best way to properly paginate over distinct `event` nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written this query in such a way:

```
MATCH
  (card:card {id: "0000000978LBtZz08W5439Mvo"})
WITH 
  card
MATCH 
  (event)-[:includes_card]->(card:card)
WITH 
  card, event ORDER BY event.created_at DESC SKIP 50 LIMIT 5
MATCH
  (card)-[includes_actor_rel:includes_actor]->(actor:user)
RETURN 
  event, actor, includes_actor_rel
```

Comment: Thanks! Just so I understand, you are applying the pagination before including the additional data? If so, does would returning card,event instead of just returning event affect the pagination? Also, what is the purpose of the first WITH card?

Comment: This ended up being the simplest solution. To answer my own questions... the only necessary WITH clause is the last one. Also, the LIMIT and SKIP clauses work operate on rows so this wouldn't affect the pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return a row for each `includes_actor_rel` relationship (some of which can share the same `event` value), and that is really what the `SKIP` and `LIMIT` clauses will apply to.

To apply the `SKIP` and `LIMIT` clauses to `event`, you can do something like this:

```
MATCH
  (card:card)<-[:includes_card]-(event:event)
WHERE
  card.id = "0000000978LBtZz08W5439Mvo"
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (card)-[includes_actor_rel:includes_actor]->(actor:user)
RETURN event, COLLECT({actor: actor, rel: includes_actor_rel}) AS data
ORDER BY event.created_at DESC
SKIP 50 
LIMIT 5;
```

This query's `COLLECT()` [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-introduction) function uses `event` as the grouping key to create a collection of all the actor/rel pairs for the same `event`. This results in a single result row per `event`, which allows the `SKIP` and `LIMIT` clauses to apply to `event`.